# Get someone else's User ID for Message

Tags: joomla, message, kunena

I'm unable to get someone's user ID from their Kunena profile to open a new private message with the recipient name already inserted. The closest I got was the following code, which inserts my own username...

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die ();

class KunenaPrivateUddeIM extends KunenaPrivate
{
protected $uddeim = null;
protected $params = null;

/**
 * @param $params
 */
public function __construct($params)
{
    $this->params = $params;

    if (!class_exists('uddeIMAPI'))
    {
        return;
    }

    $this->uddeim = new uddeIMAPI();

    if ($this->uddeim->version() < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
}

/**
 * @param $userid
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getURL($userid)
{
    static $itemid = false;

    if ($itemid === false)
    {
        $itemid = 0;

        if (method_exists($this->uddeim, 'getItemid'))
        {
            $itemid = $this->uddeim->getItemid();
        }

        if ($itemid)
        {
            $itemid = '&Itemid=' . (int) $itemid;
        }
        else
        {
            $itemid = '';
        }
    }

    return JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_uddeim&task=new&recip=' . (int) $userid . $itemid);
}

/**
 * @param $userid
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUnreadCount($userid)
{
    return $this->uddeim->getInboxUnreadMessages($userid);
}

/**
 * @param $text
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getInboxLink($text)
{
    if (!$text)
    {
        $text = JText::_('COM_KUNENA_PMS_INBOX');
    }

    return '<a href="' . JRoute::_($this->uddeim->getLinkToBox('inbox', false)) . '" rel="follow">' . $text . '</a>';
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getInboxURL()
{
$user = JFactory::getUser($userid);
return JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_uddeim&task=new&recip=' . ($user ->id));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok kunena developer has a hotfix on github for the upcomming release update. Here is the commit link https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/pull/3547

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
return JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_uddeim&task=new&recip=' . (JFactory::getUser()->id));
```

to the following 2 lines:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser($userid);
return JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_uddeim&task=new&recip=' . ($user ->id));
```

You can check this post that we have written some time ago (it was written for Joomla 2.5, but it still works, except that you have to remove the &) on how to retrieve non-cached users in Joomla: http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-retrieve-the-non-cached-user-information-from-joomla

Comment: Seems to add my own user name in the recipient field still... I read the link you sent as well

Comment: Please try now - I have fixed the code (changed `$userId` to `$userid`)

Comment: I will post the whole code so you can see if something is interfering. I will update the question right now

Comment: its the last last line that calls function getInboxURL()

Comment: You're not passing the $userid to the parameter of the function `getInboxURL`, which means that the $userid will be always 0, which means that your user will be returned. Also, check in the function that $userid contains the actual user id that you want to use.

Comment: Still been at it for days... Kunena developer said try $this->profile->userid;  but i cannot get it work wherever i put it, in the parameter, in the return, in the class... the entire code is posted at http://www.kunena.org/forum/k-4-0-general-questions/135253-getuserid-from-a-kunena-profile/